# SQLite PCL - SQLite.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm using SQLite PCL with Xamarin and, in my application, I had to download a SQLite file as a byte array (byte[]) from a web service and use this file in my app as a SQLite DataBase. Is it possible to do that with SQLite PCL?

I'm trying to do this, but I'm had SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

That's the class that I'm tryng to create a SQLite:

```
public abstract class BaseLocalDao<POCO, Entity> : ILocalDao<POCO, Entity> where POCO : class, IPOCO where Entity : class, IEntity, new()
    {
        protected IConverter<POCO, Entity> _converter;
        protected readonly SQLiteConnection _dataBase;

        public BaseLocalDao()
        {
            var controleArquivoBanco = Mvx.Resolve<IControleArquivoBanco>();

            _dataBase = new SQLiteConnection(controleArquivoBanco.GetPath());        
            _dataBase.CreateTable<Entity>();
        }
}
```

The connection is create, but when CreateTable is execute, the app throw the SQLiteExcpetion that I mentioned.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only initialise a SQLiteConnection from a file. The only way to get memory-only stream to use an in-memory database, using this syntax:

```cs
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=:memory:");
```

However you cannot initialise the database on data which is what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm not trying read a file that I created. I'm read SQLite file that was generated by web service. I read SQLite file from web service as a byte[], write in a folder in android, but when I call method CreateTable, I have excpetion.